# Difference between "vor" and "seit"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, meaning

I struggle to understand how to use these two words correctly. I cannot grasp their difference. In these next two sentences I can't see any.

> Ich habe vor einem Monat in Graz gewohnt

and

> Ich habe seit einem Monat in Graz gewohnt

Comment: I honestly don't see how those could possibly be the same. What's your mother tongue? And what does the dictionary say?

Comment: Just saw that you're from Italy... "vor" -  "anteriore a, fa"; "seit" - "da, a partire da"

Comment: The sentences I used as examples are wrong. At least the second one, as I understood, is not correct, because I cannot use Perfekt with "seit", it does not fit properly. The fact that I was trying to understand the difference between vor and seit having those "wrong" examples in mind confused me a lot. I think it is not so impossible to get it wrong then..

Comment: "Ich musste 30€ Strafe zahlen, weil ich mich nicht polizeilich gemeldet hatte. Ich habe seit einem Monat in Graz gewohnt."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Vor* is used when a spot in time is addressed, but described by an elapsed time span. *Seit* is used for unfinished time spans, meaning the action is still in progress. It's confusing because it looks similar to the construct "for/since" in English.

> Ich habe vor einem Monat in Graz gewohnt.

translates to: *I lived in Graz a month ago.*

> Ich habe seit einem Monat in Graz gewohnt.

sounds odd to me, because *habe gewohnt* indicates past tense, while *seit* indicates a present tense. Depending on the meaning I would either say:

> Ich habe einen Monat in Graz gewohnt. (I lived for a month in Graz.)

or

> Ich lebe seit einem Monat in Graz. (I have been living in Graz for a month.)

Comment: Could also be "hatte seit * in * gewohnt" and "wohnte seit * in"...(I tried to include the Google result but the link wouldn't work, just copy the phrases from this comment if you're interested). "Seit" does not automatically imply the present. The problem is that "habe" marks it as indeed the present but then it collides with the perfective idea of the past participle.

Comment: There's nothing odd with the past tense - It just means I had been living there for one month at some point in the past.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to detailed answers here, sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words.

[**Vor**](https://christianlangenegger.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/screen-shot-2012-09-02-at-20-29-28.png)

> Ich bin vor 3 Jahren nach Zürich gezogen.

I moved to Zurich 3 years ago. –> This was a single event that happened at a specific point in the past. I’m just relating it to the present by saying “3 years ago” and not “in 2009”.

[**seit**](https://christianlangenegger.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/screen-shot-2012-09-02-at-20-29-57.png)

> Ich wohne seit 3 Jahren in Zürich.

I’ve lived in Zurich for 3 years. –> the action of living in Zurich started three years ago and has continued to the present. I still live in Zurich.

[source](http://marathonsprachen.com/talking-about-the-past-in-german-seit-vs-vor/)

Comment: Wir haben 2016 - was hast Du seit 2012 gemacht, Wachkoma?

Comment: :) Exakt. Direkt nach dem Koma bin ich hierher gerannt, um eine Frage zu beantworten.

Comment: Please feel free to upload images you made yourself or that can be published under the [creative commons license 3.0 by-sa](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Comment: @Takkat Is there any difference between "uploading a picture" with "linking a picture" in terms of licence issues?

Comment: That depends on the license a site has... it is rather complicated, and we all are no lawyers. It is very likely that uploading to Imgur and then linking was not allowed too. If in doubt it is better to not use other people's images. Also see this [Meta post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/how-do-i-find-images-that-can-be-published-here) for finding images we can safely use. For now I did not remove the links to your images to give you a chance to replace them. Why not quickly draw them yourself?

Comment: @Takkat What I have learnt at the university is that with a proper linking and source giving, it is allowed to use any material unless specified differently. That is why, I have updated the links for the images. I did not draw because I wanted the people know that all of the material come from the source website, which I gave as the source.

Comment: That would be a copyright license "by attribution" which needs to be stated on the source you copied from. All content here is such plus that you can only copy to a similar licensed sitre. Links only are o.k., of course.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Vor 20 Jahren stand hier ein Haus. Jetzt ist hier ein Spielplatz.

Hier geht man 20 Jahre zurück zu einem genauen Zeitpunkt in der Vergangenheit.

> 2. Ich bin seit 20 Jahren verheiratet.

Hier wird kein Zeitpunkt angegeben, sondern ein Zeitraum/eine Zeitspanne, die angibt, wie lange nun schon.

Englischsprecher können leicht das Englische "for 20 years" (Zeitraum, wie lange nun schon)
und das Deutsche "vor 20 Jahren" (zurück zu einem Zeitpunkt) verwechseln.

Answer (score 4):

Tense does matter here.

When referring to a specific point in time in the past

- *vor*: use it like you would use *ago* in English. (20 yrs ago … / Vor 20 Jahren …)

  if something began in the past and is still going on (specific point in time)
- *seit*: use it like you would use *since* in English. (since 1958 … / seit 1958 …)

  if something began in the past and is still going on (timespan)
- *seit*: use it like you would use *for* in English. (for 20 yrs now … / seit 20 Jahren …)

So *vor* is equivalent to *ago* and *seit* is equivalent to *for/since*.

Answer (score 1):

"Vor" can be translated as "ago." And refers to a single "point in time."

"Seit" can be translated as "for." And refers to "since the time period, up to the present.

Ich habe vor einem Monat in Graz gewohnt. I lived in Graz one month **ago.**

Ich habe seit einem Monat in Graz gewohnt. I've lived in Graz **for** one month, that is, continuing to the present **since** a month ago.

Comment: The distinctions are more subtle than this. Germans often give themselves away with inappropriate use of "since". For example "I have lived in London since three years", which should be "for the last three years" or "since three years ago".

Comment: @MichaelKay: "Seit" can be translated as "for." And refers to "since the time period, up to the present" (mine) corresponds to your construction: "should be "for the last three years" or "since three years ago". We're basically in agreement.

Comment: Your interpretation of the last sentence is wrong. The sentence does not say "continuing to the present since then"

Comment: @tofro: OK, changed it to "since a month ago" for clarity.