# How to use “seit” and “vor” with “verschwinden”

Tags: verb, time, tense

The questions are on these sentences, where (a) is lifted out of [this older post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20061/difference-between-vor-and-seit), and (b) is from a vocabulary workbook.  I made up (c) and (d); so they may have problems.

> (a) Ich lebe seit einem Monat in Graz.
>
> (b) Unsere Katze ist seit Tagen verschwunden.
>
> (c) Unsere Katze verschwand vor Tagen.
>
> (d) Unsere Katze ist vor Tagen verschwunden.

Basically I am trying to understand how *seit* and *vor* may interact with [grammatical aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect).  Feel free to answer in German.

#### Questions

1. Am I OK to assimilate (b) to (a) as follows?

   - *lebe* in (a) denotes what is true (in progess) for the whole time between a month ago and now.
   - *ist verschwunden* in (b) is not a substitute for Präteritum.  It is a true Perfekt.  The "present result of the past event" is what is true for the whole time between days ago and now.
   - We may say that the "present" (imperfect, progressive) aspect of *lebe* and the "present" component of the resultative aspect of *ist verschwunden* respectively satisfy the aspectual requirement of *seit*.
2. Is (d) grammatical and idiomatic?
3. If yes to 2, am I OK to understand (d) this way?

   - Because *vor* requires a verb denoting an event (viz. a verb in the "aorist" aspect), *ist verschwunden* is now a substitute for Präteritum.
   - That is, (d) now means the same thing as (c).
   - Unlike (b), you can say (d) even if the cat has come back subsequently.

**Background**

I tried to get something like (b) with *vorbeigehen*, but *Er ist seit Tagen an unserem Hause vorbeigegangen* didn’t seem to work.  I think there is no sense of *ist vorbeigegangen* that is comparable to *ist verschwunden*, something that can remain and persist (be in progress).

Comment: Basically yes, yes, yes, no. Please note that _vor_ tends to be used with a qualifier (e.g. _vor zwei Tagen, vor einigen Wochen, vor vielen Monaten_), at least more so than _seit_.

Comment: @Crissov Thank you. I am sorry I got rid of question 4 (to which your *no*), which used to ask whether the bad sentence (Er ist seit Tagen an unserem Hause vorbeigegangen) worked.  When I realized it didn't, I moved it to background, not realizing that you had already commented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence *Die Katze ist verschwunden* has two different interpretations:

- On the one hand, *ist* can be the auxiliary used when forming the perfect tense. In that case, *verschwunden* is part of the perfect form and the sentence is analogous to *Der Mann ist gestorben* or *Der Hahn hat (!) gekräht*; it indicates that an event (disappearance of the cat) happened in the past.
- On the other hand, *ist* can be the present-tense copula. In that case, *verschwunden* is used as an adjective, analogous to *Der Mann ist tot* or *Der Hahn ist wach*; it indicates a current state, namely that the whereabouts of the cat are unknown.

This ambiguity is only possible because *verschwinden* belongs to the group of verbs that form the perfect tense with *sein* instead of *haben*.

Adding a time specification like in your sentences (b) and (d) resolves the ambiguity because *vor drei Tagen* etc. only makes sense in connection with a past event, whereas *seit drei Tagen* only works in connection with a state that persists. Applied to the structurally analogous sentences I introduced above, this means that you can use only one of these constructions for each sentence:

> Der Mann ist vor drei Tagen gestorben. Der Hahn hat vor einer Stunde gekräht.
>   Der Mann ist seit drei Tagen tot. Der Hahn ist seit einer Stunde wach.

(*Der Hahn hat seit einer Stunde gekräht* is in fact possible, but would mean that the cock crowed continuously or repeatedly over the course of the last hour.)

Now to your questions:

1. In (b), *ist (verschwunden)* is not perfect but present tense (not of *verschwinden*, but of *sein*). That’s why it can’t be replaced with a preterite.
2. Whether (d) is grammatical and idiomatic … mostly yes, but I hesitate to “approve” of it because of *vor Tagen*. As Crissov already mentioned in a comment, *vor Tagen* sounds strange except in specific contexts; *schon vor Tagen* will often work, and *vor zwei Tagen* (or any number) is fine.
3. Yes, (c) and (d) are equivalent, and both can be said – unlike (b) – when the cat has since reappeared:

   > Unsere Katze ist vor drei Tagen verschwunden. Heute früh ist sie endlich wieder aufgetaucht.

Comment: Thank you. It's much easier to think *ist* is a copula than to try to squeeze a "present" aspect out of a Perfekt. But questions. Suppose (i) the cock crows from 5 a.m. to 6 vs. (ii) from 6 to 7, and at 7 I declare (p) *Der Hahn hat seit einer Stunde gekräht* vs. (q) *Der Hahn kräht seit einer Stunde*. Am I right to think: (p) means (i); (q) means (ii)? (That is my guess because (q) looks just like (a) from the main question.)

Comment: (q) means (ii), but (p) also means (ii) – or possibly 6.00 to 6.59 or something like that. Definitely not (i). In practice,  (q) occurs far more often.

Comment: For (i), one would use the preterite (*Der Hahn krähte seit einer Stunde*)?

Comment: It’s not impossible to say that, but it would need to be clear from context that the point of reference is 6.00.